# Spring Boot WEB MVC : Not getting the value instead getting package name as an output

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

The output which I am getting **HELLO USER DATAcom.example.demo.model.Employee@209e65b**

and the output which I need **HELLO USER DATA Employee(empId=99,empName=AA,empSal=200.0**

[Please check the image for project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Gm66.png)

```
**Employee.java(Model Class)**

package com.example.demo.model;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Employee {

    private Integer empId;
    private String empName;
    private Double empSalary;
}
 
**EmployeeController.java(Controller Class)**

package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.example.demo.model.Employee;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    @GetMapping("/reg")
    public String showReg()
    {
        return "Register";
    }

    
    @PostMapping("/save")
    public String readform(
            @ModelAttribute Employee employee,
            Model model
            )
    {
        System.out.println(employee);
        model.addAttribute("emp",employee); 
        return "data";
    }

}

**data.html**
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>
            REGISTER FORM 
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>
            HELLO USER DATA<span th:text="${emp}"></span>
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>

**Register.html**
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>
            REGISTER FORM 
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>
            <h2>Employee Registration Page</h2>
            <form th:action="@{/employee/save}" method="post">
                  
                  ID : <input type="text" name="empId"/>
                NAME : <input type="text" name="empName"/>
              SALARY : <input type="text" name="empSalary"/>
              
              <button type="submit" Text-align: center>CREATE</button>
            
            </form>
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>


**Main_PAGE_CODE**
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringBootThyemleaf21Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySpringBootThyemleaf21Application.class, args);
    }

}

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am getting the package and class name as an output instead of the output data which needs to be fetched from the model class and need to be displayed while using at the time of model.addattribute -> at this point I am adding the object of the model class "employee"

Comment: It looks like Lombok is not effective. Eclipse UI has an option for it: check for 'Enable annotation processing'.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same issue and the solution is that you are missing toString() method in model class. Autogenerate it and it would solve the issue like in my case it was:
@Override
public String toString() {
return "Person{" +
"id=" + id +
", name='" + name + ''' +
", location='" + location + ''' +
'}';
}